# Distinguishing between prepositions associated with “lack”

Tags: prepositions

> The opinions that he expresses are lacking **in** intellectual depth.
> <sub>Source: Vocabulary Worksheet [*9HVocabL6.doc*](http://shenandoahshs.sharpschool.net/common/pages/DisplayFile.aspx?itemId=5541810), from Strasburg High School’s [documents for English 9](http://shenandoahshs.sharpschool.net/faculty__staff/english/english_9/documents/?portalId=3201788&pageId=5540473&objectId.314127=5541758&contextId.314127=5540474)</sub>

Would you throw a light on the difference between **“lack of”** and **“lack in”**?

When, where, or how do you use the prepositions “of” or “in” with “lack”?

Which one would you rather use? Do you would discern a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The opinions that he expresses are lacking in intellectual depth.

*Lacking* in your example is a ‘deverbal adjective’—a participle which has lost all sense of its verbal origin. When it takes a complement this must be expressed as a preposition phrase with *in*.

The verb *lack* takes an ordinary Direct Object. However, it is stative, like *live* or *know*, so it is not ordinarily cast in the progressive construction. If you want to use the verb you should employ the simple construction:

> The  opinions that he expresses lack intellectual depth.

The senses of the two expressions, adjective and verb, are slightly different. The adjective *lacking* implies a deficiency: his opinions have insufficient intellectual depth. The verb *lack* implies complete absence: his opinions have **no** intellectual depth.

ADDED:
The noun *lack*, derived from the verb, ordinarily expresses its object with *of*:

> His lack of intellectual depth is depressing."

A noun derived from a transitive verb usually (but not always) expresses its object with *of*. But other prepositions may be employed to express nuance. For instance, *lack* may also take an object with *in*, to express the same deficiency as the deverbal adjective:

> A certain lack in intellectual depth is evident in his opinions.

Comment: However, what about of? lack of? what is the difference between this one and those ones?

Comment: @nima_persian See my addition.

Comment: So, eventually, lack of or lack? is there any difference between these?

Comment: @nima_persian The difference between verb and noun.

Comment: +1 But I really think I'd write that last sentence with *of*. Are you saying it should only be written with *in* or  are your saying it can be written with either?

Comment: @Jim I'm saying it might be written with *in*, though *of* is more usual.

Answer (score 0):

**Lack(ing)** without *in* is more absolute and direct.
**lacking in** is a "side quality".
(my two cents opinion :)
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lacking+in

Comment: How is “lacking in” a side quality? What is a side quality? What about “lack of” (from the question)? What are you pointing to in dictionary.com’s definition of “lack”?